# Call top level class function in php

Tags: php, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a scenario, in that, I have three separate classes file A.php, B.php, C.php.

A.php is independent file having some functions and 'B' extends 'A', and 'C' extendes 'B'.

Here In 'C.php' file i am able to access function of 'B.php' but not of 'A.php'.

Here is my structure -

In A.php -

```
class A {
    public function testA(){
        echo "AA";
    }
}
```

In B.php -

```
class B extends A{
    public function testB(){
        echo "BB";
    }
}
```

In C.php -

```
class C extends B{
    //Here i am able to call class B's function like 
    public function testC(){
        $this->testB();
    }

    //but not able to call Class A's function 
    public function testC1(){
        $this->testA();  // Here its giving error
    }
}
```

Please let me know is it the right way to do it. How can I access 'A.php's' function in 'C.php'

Regards

Comment: What error?! https://3v4l.org/3E2Z7

Comment: The updated code works so I have no idea what issue you're having now. However, it's a pretty strange example though. There would be no reason for `testC()` and `testC1()` to exist since you could just call `testA()` and `testB()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you post the error message, it's most likely about out of memory, right? That's because you have an infinite loop in your code.

In class `C`, you have

```
public function testB() 
{ 
    $this->testB(); 
}
```

which is a method that calls it self forever, using up all the memory you have.

If you want to call `testB()` from the parent class, you should call it like:

```
public function testB() 
{ 
    parent::testB(); 
}
```

If you have extended a class and you override a method (like `testB()` in your `C` class) and want to call the parents implementation, you need to call it using `parent::` instead of `$this->`.

[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/MbbuE)

Comment: @Atul - So what happens? Does it work? Do you get any errors? If yes, then what is the error message? The updated code has no issues as far as I can see? It works when testing it: https://3v4l.org/7RpOE

Comment: @Atul - If this answer help you get your code working, then please accept it. Also, if it did help you, then you should rollback your updates to the question since it completely change it. The first code had issues, the updated code doesn't. Future visitors won't have a clue what the issue or what the answer are talking about.